# Creating C++ class from C, can I pass C++ objects to C++ constructor in C?

Tags: c++, c

```
class A {
    A(B b){

    }
    A(C c){

    }
}
class B {
    B(char * s) {}
}
class C {
    C(char * s) {}
}
```

Now, if I create C code to create `A`, I might want to create `A` from `B` and `C` instances, because its constructor supports both classes as inputs

```
extern "C" A* A_init_from_B(char *s);
extern "C" A* A_init_from_C(char *s);
```

Is there a way to create `B` and `C` instances to pass to `A`? Example:

```
extern "C" A* A_init_from_B(char *s) {
    B b("hello");
    return new A(b);
}
extern "C" A* A_init_from_C(char *s) {
    C c("hello");
    return new A(c);
}
```

**Or does C can only create pointers to C++ classes? Aren't normal C++ class instances allowed in C?** I know I could create constructors in A that take pointers to A and B, but can it be done without pointers?

Comment: In C you can make `void` pointers, pointers to primitive types such as `float`, and pointers to `struct`ures.  The only thing that *might* work is a `void` pointer.

Comment: Your code should work the way you have it.  Compile your `extern "C"` functions as C++, then call them from C code.

Comment: @SidS I'm trying to understand how C++ objects can be created in C. Is there a place where I can read about? If I can create non pointer objects, why do people use pointers interacting with C++ code?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs You don't create the C++ objects in C. You call a `extern "C"` function that in turn is implemented in C++ and creates the object and returns a pointer (probably a `void*`) to the object. Whenever that object needs to be used, you pass the pointer to the appropriate `extern "C"` function (also implemented in C++) that `reinterpret_cast<>`s the pointer back to a pointer of the correct type and performs the actions needed.

Comment: `extern "C"` does not mean "compile this code as C". It is still C++.

Comment: Just a note on the C++ part of your example, classes B and C should be defined before A since A uses them.

Answer (score 3):

`extern "C"` can be used in C++ to indicate that you are using C based name mangling/linking.

A C++ function that is `extern "C"` can be called from C code or from C++ code, and can be implemented in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how it can be done with comments in the code.

*extc.h*

```
#ifndef EXTC_H
#define EXTC_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <string>

// the C++ classes, defined as usual

class B {
public:
    B(const std::string& s);
    const std::string& get_str() const;
private:
    std::string str_;
};

class C {
public:
    C(const std::string& s);
    const std::string& get_str() const;
private:
    std::string str_;
};

class A {
public:
    A(const B& b);
    A(const C& c);
    const std::string& get_str() const;
private:
    std::string str_;
};

#else /* C interface */

/* C versions of handles used to store pointers to the objects */
typedef struct { void* ptr_; } AHANDLE;
typedef struct { void* ptr_; } BHANDLE;
typedef struct { void* ptr_; } CHANDLE;
/* C++ versions of the above handles are only used internally and
 * can be found in extc.cpp */

/* prototypes for functions matching what you can do with the C++
   interface as good as possible */

AHANDLE A_create_from_B(BHANDLE);
AHANDLE A_create_from_C(CHANDLE);
void A_destroy(AHANDLE);
const char* A_get_str(AHANDLE);

BHANDLE B_create(const char*);
void B_destroy(BHANDLE);
const char* B_get_str(BHANDLE);

CHANDLE C_create(const char*);
void C_destroy(CHANDLE);
const char* C_get_str(CHANDLE);

#endif
#endif
```

*extc.cpp*

```
#include "extc.h"

// Implementation of the C++ member functions
B::B(const std::string& str) : str_(str) {}
const std::string& B::get_str() const { return str_; }
C::C(const std::string& str) : str_(str) {}
const std::string& C::get_str() const { return str_; }
A::A(const B& b) : str_(b.get_str()) {}
A::A(const C& c) : str_(c.get_str()) {}
const std::string& A::get_str() const { return str_; }

// C++ versions of the handles used by C code
struct AHANDLE { A* ptr_; };
struct BHANDLE { B* ptr_; };
struct CHANDLE { C* ptr_; };

// implementation of the interface to use from C
// (written in C++, but with C linkage)

extern "C" {
    BHANDLE B_create(const char* str) {
        return {new B(str)};
    }
    void B_destroy(BHANDLE h) {
        delete h.ptr_;
    }
    const char* B_get_str(BHANDLE h) {
        return h.ptr_->get_str().data();
    }

    CHANDLE C_create(const char* str) {
        return {new C(str)};
    }
    void C_destroy(CHANDLE h) {
        delete h.ptr_;
    }
    const char* C_get_str(CHANDLE h) {
        return h.ptr_->get_str().data();
    }

    AHANDLE A_create_from_B(BHANDLE h) {
        return {new A(*h.ptr_)};
    }
    AHANDLE A_create_from_C(CHANDLE h) {
        return {new A(*h.ptr_)};
    }
    void A_destroy(AHANDLE h) {
        delete h.ptr_;
    }
    const char* A_get_str(AHANDLE h) {
        return h.ptr_->get_str().data();
    }
}
```

You need to add error handling to return handles with `ptr_` set to `nullptr` in case `new` throws etc.

Finally a small C program to use the C interface:

*extmain.c*

```
#include "extc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    BHANDLE b = B_create("Hello world");
    CHANDLE c = C_create("Goodbyt");
    printf("b  = %s\n", B_get_str(b));
    printf("c  = %s\n", C_get_str(c));
    AHANDLE a1 = A_create_from_B(b);
    AHANDLE a2 = A_create_from_C(c);
    printf("a1 = %s\n", A_get_str(a1));
    printf("a2 = %s\n", A_get_str(a2));

    A_destroy(a1);
    A_destroy(a2);
    B_destroy(b);
    C_destroy(c);
}
```

Compilation of the C++ code and the C code:

```
% g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -c extc.cpp
% gcc -std=c11 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o extmain extmain.c extc.o -lstdc++
```